# Ataque CSRF Token - Entendiendo CSRF

Tags: spring-boot, csrf

Leyendo la [documentación de CSRF de Springboot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html)  hay un ejemplo de ataque CSRF y hay una parte del ejemplo que no entiendo muy bien.

Describiré brevemente la documentación para llegar al punto que no entiendo:

Comienzo:

Assume that your bank’s website provides a form that allows transferring money from the currently logged in user to another bank account. For example, the HTTP request might look like:

```
POST /transfer HTTP/1.1
Host: bank.example.com
Cookie: JSESSIONID=randomid; Domain=bank.example.com; Secure; HttpOnly
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

amount=100.00&routingNumber=1234&account=9876
```

Nota: hasta aquí todo bien, continuo

Now pretend you authenticate to your bank’s website and then, without logging out, visit an evil website. The evil website contains an HTML page with the following form:

```
<form action="https://bank.example.com/transfer" method="post">
<input type="hidden"
    name="amount"
    value="100.00"/>
<input type="hidden"
    name="routingNumber"
    value="evilsRoutingNumber"/>
<input type="hidden"
    name="account"
    value="evilsAccountNumber"/>
<input type="submit"
    value="Win Money!"/>
</form>
```

You like to win money, so you click on the submit button. In the process, you have unintentionally transferred $100 to a malicious user. This happens because, while the evil website cannot see your cookies, the cookies associated with your bank are still sent along with the request.

Culminando con el texto de la  documentación aquí es donde surge mi duda, entendiendo que si el usuario tiene una sesión abierta en su pagina de banco y a su vez ingresa a un sitio malicioso, el sitio malicioso se encargaría de hacer la transferencia automatica al usuario presionar el botón `Win Money!`, adicional el formulario del sitio malicioso tiene dos campos ocultos que son el "RoutingNumber" y el "Account Number", y es aquí donde no entiendo, cómo hace el  sitio web malicioso para obtener esos datos, el routing number y el account number si son datos que pertenecen a otra aplicación.

Nota: Entiendo lo que hace el CSRF en cada Request, pero en el ejemplo no entiendo como ocurre esa captura de esos dos datos del sitio malicioso, pareciera que lo hace a través de las cookies pero no entiendo técnicamente el cómo. Actualmente formo parte de un equipo que esta desarrollando una aplicación de pagos y me gustaría tener totalmente claro como se realizan los ataques csrf, al menos el del ejemplo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No estás entendiendo correctamente la documentación. Los valores de los inputs son parte del formulario malicioso, en la web maliciosa. Lo que se trata de explicar es que la solicitud (`request`) desde el sitio malicioso es exactamente igual que la solicitud desde el banco, dando lugar a que se pueda tomar como legítima, causando un problema de seguridad. Lee la sección 19.2 de esa documentación que enlazas, ya que el contexto completo del ejemplo que plantea se deduce allí. Saludos

Comment: "No estás entendiendo correctamente la documentación. Los valores de los inputs son parte del formulario malicioso". Eso lo entiendo perfectamente y lo explico en la descripción y también describo exactamente que es lo que no entiendo. El banco necesita los datos que van escondidos en el formulario malicioso para hacerse una transferencia a si mismo desde el dinero del usuario. Lo que pregunto es como hace para obtener el numero de cuenta y el routing number que serán datos requeridos en el backend para realizar la transferencia.

Comment: Esto: *y es aquí donde no entiendo, cómo hace el sitio web malicioso para obtener esos datos, el routing number y el account number si son datos que pertenecen a otra aplicación.* No son datos de otra aplicación, son datos del formulario malicioso. Son las coordenadas de la cuenta maliciosa. Si haces clic en el botón, tu dinero se va a transferir a esas coordenadas.

Comment: Claro pero es que un banco al realizar una transferencia no solo utiliza los datos del beneficiario tambien necesita los datos de quien realiza la transferencia, esos son los datos que no entiendo como los obtiene, a quien le va a debitar.

Comment: *esos son los datos que no entiendo como los obtiene, a quien le va a debitar*. Los obtiene de la cookie. Es lo que se trata de explicar en la documentación. Al hacer la solicitud desde la web maliciosa, se envía la cookie previamente almacenada de la sesión de usuario de la web del banco.